# Is it necessary to use EL to get the "current" bean in JSF?

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to fix some bugs in a JSF applications that,  among other things, has a session-scoped bean "userBean" of class "UserBean" declared in "faces-config.xml".  One of the methods has a line of code as follows:

```
public void doSomething() {
    ...
    UserBean userBean = (UserBean) facesContext.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(facesContext, "#{userBean}", UserBean.class);
    ...
}
```

Is there any reason to use that long expression instead of just "this"?  Or if everything is declared properly,  can I be confident that the instance the method is executing on is in fact the bean associated with the session?

Comment: Looks crazy. Though check there isn't an unmanaged instance of `UserBean` being created somewhere else, which would be a design smell of a different order.

Answer (score 2):

You can test if it is the same bean simply comparing the references and triggering an execution of the method to see what happens:

```
public void doSomething() {
    UserBean userBean = (UserBean) facesContext.getApplication().
      evaluateExpressionGet(facesContext, "#{userBean}", UserBean.class);
    if (this == userBean){
        System.out.println("\nIt is the same bean, time for some cleanup!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("\nThere is something very weird going on here...");
    }
}
```

Remember, `this` and `userBean` are just references, pointing to a region in the memory. If they are always the same, you could safely substitute the expression by `this`.

I can see this happening if maybe someone wrote the code firstly in another place, and then someone refactored it moving this piece of code to the same bean and forgot to change this reference.